# Confusing React useEffect hook behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm new to React and just practicing useEffect hooks after going through a hooks course.

I have a button to toggle state change of arrowState.

```
export default function Test() {
  const [arrowState, setArrowState] = useState(true);
  const [arrowChange, setArrowChange] = useState(false);

  
  const toggleButton = () => {
    return setArrowState((arrowState) => {
      return !arrowState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={toggleButton}
        >
          Toggle Arrow
        </button>
      </div>
      {arrowChange && <Notific />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Then I have a useEffect hook which changes state of arrowChange.
Also have a timeout to change state of arrowChange to false - thereby auto-disappearing the button after 2 secs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("first line of useEffect.arrowChange is ", arrowChange);
    setArrowChange(true);
    console.log(
      "immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is ",
      arrowChange
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is ", arrowChange);
      arrowChange && setArrowChange(false);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      console.log("cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is ", arrowChange);
      setArrowChange(false);
    };
  }, [arrowState]);
```

Based on it, I'm displaying another button with a message.

```
function Notific() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setArrowChange(false)}
      >
        Arrow state has been changed
      </button>
    );
  }
```

As you can see, I'm logging some messages to see the effect. I'm surprised to see that even after setting arrowChange to true at the beginning of useEffect hook, it's still showing false at alternate events.

Check these console logs:

```
cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  false
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  true
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  true

Test.js:70 cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  false
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  false
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  false

Test.js:70 cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  false
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  true
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  true

Test.js:70 cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  false
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  false
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  false

Test.js:70 cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  false
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  true
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  true
```

Comment: 1. State update is asynchronous. 2. State is constant within a particular render of a component. 3. Component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. 4. Callback function of the `useEffect` hook has a closure over the state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's too much theory for a beginner like me. I don't understand.

Comment: React batches all the useState updates and commits them at once since it is async. But `console.log` prints the value at the time when it is encountered and does not wait for react to update the status before logging the info

Comment: See: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLatest.md

Answer (score 4):

To understand the output of the code, you need to understand the fundamental concepts of how react updates the state and the concept of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

#### State updates are asynchronous

Every call to state setter function such as `setArrowChange` is scheduled - state is not updated immediately.

As a result, logging the value of `arrowChange` *immediately after* calling `setArrowChange` will log the old value of `arrowChange`.

#### State is constant within a particular render of a component

State is constant; this means that irrespective of how many times you call the state setter function, component can't see the updated state until it re-renders.

#### Callback function of setTimeout has a closure over the state

When you create a function is javascript, it forms a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over its surrounding scope.

In your case, the callback function of `setTimeout` will log the value of `arrowChange` was in-effect when the callback function was created.

If at the time of `setTimeout` call, `arrowChange` is `false`, and before the timer expires, you update the state to `true`, the callback function will still log `false` because of the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

#### Cleanup function of the useEffect hook has a closure over the state

The `cleanup` function also has a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the `arrowChange`; it logs the value of `arrowChange` that was in-effect when the cleanup function was created and returned from the callback function of the `useEffect` hook.

Now let's take a look at the first group of `console.log` output.

#### first group:

> ```
> cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is false 
> Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is true 
> Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is true
> Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is true
> ```

First line of output

```
cleaning up arrowchange. arrowChange is  false
```

is from the cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook that executes:

- Before running the `useEffect` again
- Before the component unmounts

As explained above, it logs the value of the `arrowChange` which it *closed over* when the cleanup function of the `useEffect` was created. Output of the cleanup function suggests that:

1. Value of the `arrowChange` was `false` when the cleanup function was created and returned from the `useEffect` hook's callback function
2. The initial value of the `arrowChange` is `false`, so this output if from the cleanup function that was most likely created when the `useEffect` hook executed for the first time, *after* the initial render of the component

Next three lines

```
Test.js:57 first line of useEffect.arrowChange is  true
Test.js:59 immediately after setArrowChange to true. arrowChange is  true
Test.js:65 first line of setTimeOut. arrowChange is  true
```

log the latest value of `arrowChange` which is most likely because of `setArrowChange(true)` call in the second line of the `useEffect` hook that executed *after* the initial render of the component.

If you observe the output of other groups of `console.log` outputs, you will notice that the value of `arrowChange` logged by the cleanup function is *opposite* to the value logged by the `console.log` statements inside the callback function of the `useEffect` hook.

The reason for this is that the cleanup function is from the *previous* execution of the `useEffect` hook and it logs the value of `arrowChange` that was in-effect during the *previous* execution of the `useEffect` hook.

`console.log` statements inside the callback function of the `useEffect` hook log the latest value of the `arrowChange` and in the next execution of the `useEffect` hook, this latest value will become the *previous value* and the opposite of this latest value will become the *latest value*.

Comment: well explained. I get the concept of closure over surrounding scope at render time. It completely makes sense now. Thanks for the effort.